# Cannot get on_failure_callback working on Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

There is a valid TelegramOperator function:

```
    send_telegram_message = TelegramOperator(
        task_id="send_telegram_message",
        token="<token>",
        chat_id="<chat ID>",
        text="Some notification"
    )
```

It works that way:

`t1 >> send_telegram_message`

But I want it to notify me about *failed* tasks. I've tried to put it into default args, but it causes 'broken DAG' error somewhy and I cannot see the reason in UI:

```
    default_args={
        "depends_on_past": False,
        "email_on_failure": False,
        "email_on_retry": False,
        "on_failure_callback": send_telegram_message,
        "retries": 1,
        "retry_delay": timedelta(seconds=30)
    },
```

---

If I put on_failure_callback param into task parameters, it simply doesn't work either in on_failure_callback or on_success_callback cases (no error traceback too, just successfully completed task in UI):

```
    t1 = BashOperator(
            task_id="entering_virtual_environment",
            depends_on_past=False,
            bash_command="source /home/fitwist/airflow/airflow_env/bin/activate",
            retries=2,
            on_failure_callback=send_telegram_message
    )
```

---

I've also tried to create higher order function and put it inside DAG (nothing is being send to Telegram):

```
    def task_success_callback(context):
        op = TelegramOperator(
            task_id="send_telegram_message",
            token="<token>",
            chat_id="<chat ID>",
            text="Some notification"
    
        )
        op.execute(context)
    
    
    with DAG(
        "monthly_effectiveness",
        default_args={
            ...
        },
        ...
        on_failure_callback=send_telegram_message,
        ...
    ) as dag:
    ...
```

---

Using direct function call in task flow causes nothing, not even an error:

```
    t1 >> t2 >> send_telegram_message
    send_telegram_message >> send_failed_telegram_message
```

How do I get failure notifications in Telegram?

Comment: `on_failure_callback` is supposed to be a plain-old Python function, not an Airflow Operator or Task.  If you want a *Task* to execute on failure, you can set up a [branch](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/airflow-branch-operator) in the DAG.

Answer (score 0):

From docs:

> on_failure_callback: A function or list of functions to be called when a DagRun of this dag fails. A context dictionary is passed as a single parameter to this function.

So your callback function should accept one positional argument.

Example callback function:

```py
def my_failure_callback(_context):
    print("*****************DAG failed****************")


dag = DAG("my_dag",
          start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
          catchup=False,
          on_failure_callback=my_failure_callback)


op1 = BashOperator(task_id="explicit_failure",
                   bash_command="fail this",
                   dag=dag)
```

Errors when callback functions cannot be executed and logs printed inside the callback functions will be available in the scheduler logs `<airflow-logs-path>/logs/scheduler/<date>/<dag-name>.py.log`.

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64870656/implementing-branching-in-airflow) helped me to get the logic needed:

```
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule

[T1, T2, T3, ...] >> DummyOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id="task_a",
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED
)
```

Comment: In this context is the `DummyOperator` supposed to mimic a failure callback? Instead, I'd recommend using a Python function as the callback function instead of a TelegramOperator. You can use the [TelegramHook](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-telegram/stable/_api/airflow/providers/telegram/hooks/telegram/index.html) to connect to Telegram.